# Split char array in 'C' to CSV's

Tags: c, string, replace

I need to split a char array into CSV's. Actually we can do the reverse of it using `strtok()` like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
 char str[] ="This,a,sample,string.";
 char * pch;
 printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
 pch = strtok (str,",");
 while (pch != NULL)
 {
   printf ("%s\n",pch);
   pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

But in my case, there's an char array suppose `char bits[1024]="abcdefghijklmn"`. I need to get the output as `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,m,n`.

Is there any function or library to do this i.e. in terms of raw meaning, for every character it has to put a comma.

Comment: No, there is no such standard C library function.  So you must make your own using a simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for a null terminated string. But it will leave a dangling comma at the end.

```
void tokenise(char *s, char *d)
{
 while(*d++ = *s++) *d++ = ',';
}
```

If you know the length of the string already, you can pass that through. This will not leave a dangling comma.

```
void tokenise(char *s, char *d, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    while((*d++ = *s++) && ((i++)<(length-1))) *d++ = ',';
}
```

In both examples, `s` is a pointer to the source string and `d` points to the output tokenised string. It is up to the calling code to ensure the buffer `d` points to is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over the string until you hit the end-of-string `'\0'` character. Or use the length of the data in the array (which may be smaller than the array size) and use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: :) I don't have any `\0` here.

Comment: A C string always ends with `\0`

Comment: @xen-0 Right. What the string here I receive is a bunch of data from Server. Like some 1 to n packets.

Comment: @highlander141 As you initialize the array to a string, the compiler will automatically put the terminator character there for you. Otherwise, if you have the length of the data in the array (which may be smaller than the size of the array) you can use that instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the solution needs new buffer of `2*N` size and splitting I guess

Comment: @VoidPointer There's no need for a buffer at all, if the comma-separated data is just going out to a stream.

Comment: @unwind I had some other idea based on new buffer and given it as answer. I suspect OP needs that kind of answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple function from old basic :

```
// ............................................................. string word at

char * word_at(char *tString, int upTo, char *dilim) {

     int wcount;
     char *rString, *temp;
    temp= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tString)+1));
    strcpy(temp, tString);

    rString= strtok(temp, dilim);
    wcount=1;

    while (rString != NULL){
        if (wcount==upTo) { 
     return rString;
        }
        rString= strtok(NULL, dilim);
        wcount++;
    }
   return tString ;
  }
```

parameter : string , index and character delimiter 
return : word : ( char *)

Answer (score 0):

If you find easy to implement it, then this could help you to start

```
char* split_all( char arr[], char ch )
{
    char *new, *ptr;

    new = ptr = calloc( 1, 2*strlen( arr ) ); // FIXME : Error checks

    for( ; *(arr + 1) ; new++, arr++ )
    {
            *new = *arr;
            new++;
            *new = ch;
    }

    *new = *arr;
    return ptr;
}
```

You can re-use, optimize this for your requirement. Its a quick and dirty solution, feel free to fix it..